# My Barnsley Fern is Too Skinny

Tags: java, canvas, graphics, jframe, fractals

I'm new to Java programming, and recently I've decided to pick the topic of fractals for a school essay. However, the first step of writing my essay requires me to recreate the Barnsley fern using Java code. When I tried this, my Barnsley fern looked too skinny compared to the other ones I've seen on the web. I checked Wikipedia to make sure the numbers and probabilities of my affine transformations were correct, but the same, skinny fern was produced. Can someone help me? I recently dove into the realm of BufferedImage, hearing that that was the better way of rendering pixels, but I'm still unsure of how it works. Is the Graphics style of painting unreliable or something? This is my code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Canvas;

public class Fern extends Canvas{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int ITERATION = 100000;

    public  Fern() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics window)
    {
        double x = .5;
        double y = 0;
        window.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        window.drawRect(200,600,1,1);
        Color color;
        for(int i = 0; i<ITERATION; i++){
            double chance = (Math.random());
            if(chance<.85){
                x=.85*x+.04*y; //x=.85*x+.04*y;
                y=-.04*x+.85*y+1.6; //y=-.04*x+.85*y+1.6;
                color = new Color(Color.GREEN.getRGB());
            }
            else if(chance<.86){
                x=0; //x=0;
                y=.16*y; //y=.16*y;
                color = new Color(Color.BLUE.getRGB());
            }
            else if(chance<.93){
                x=.2*x-.26*y; //x=.2*x-.26*y;
                y=.23*x+.22*y+1.6; //y=.23*x+.22*y+1.6;
                color = new Color(Color.RED.getRGB());
            }
            else{
                x=-.15*x+.28*y; //x=-.15*x+.28*y;
                y=.26*x+.24*y+.44; //y=.26*x+.24*y+.44;
                color = new Color(Color.ORANGE.getRGB());
            }
            window.setColor(color);
            window.fillRect((int)(66*x)+200,(int)(66*-y)+675,1,1);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the Runner class provided by APlusCompSci.com with a few tweaks.

```
//© A+ Computer Science  -  www.apluscompsci.com

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GraphicsRunner extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int HEIGHT= 800;

    public GraphicsRunner()
    {
        super("Barnsley Fern");
        setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);  

        getContentPane().add(new Fern());
        setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        GraphicsRunner run = new GraphicsRunner();
    }
}
```

Sorry I could not provide a picture of the misshapen fern. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're missing a comment next to `WIDTH = 500;` to explain that it does `//WIDTH = 500;`. Just kidding ;-)

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to mention I had the comments there because I was experimenting with the equations' values and didn't want to lose the original ones.

Answer (score 7):

The following lines most certainly contain a very common error :

```
  x=.85*x+.04*y; //x=.85*x+.04*y;
  y=-.04*x+.85*y+1.6; //y=-.04*x+.85*y+1.6;
```

Because you change the value for x on the first line, so the second line (y) gives the wrong result.

You should write :

```
  int x2=.85*x+.04*y; //x=.85*x+.04*y;
  y=-.04*x+.85*y+1.6; //y=-.04*x+.85*y+1.6;
  x = x2;
```

using a temporary variable allows you to have correct result for both x AND y.

Comment: Or you could do something like `newX=...` and `newY=…` and then assign those values to `x` and `y`. Might be a bit more readable in my opinion.

Comment: Oh yes, I remember the exact feeling when I saw my first ever rotating cube gradually flatten out. :)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't catch that! Thank you @Orabîg. It looks perfect now. Love this website for how fast the questions are answered.

Comment: @StephenAzatian I know many developers who played around with graphics, there's not one of them who didn't fall into this trap at first. So don't feel bad about it.